# How to fix 'Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.' when scraping websites with rvest?

Tags: r, http, rvest

Trying to scrape through a series of websites. Links are in a data frame called linksRaw. It works when running just a single url through the html_node and html_text. I have added a for loop in order to work through every url in linksRaw. When I added this loop it gave me this error: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503. I have tried adding randomized time delays, but I've found no luck. I also read through some of the other posts on the site about this, but none of them were super helpful. Any advice would be strongly appreciated.

```
to_get <- linksRaw
pb <- progress_estimated(length(to_get))
for(i in 1:nrow(linksRaw)) {
pb$tick()$print()
row <- linksRaw[i, ]
url <- row
webpage <- read_html(url)
contentHTML <- html_nodes(webpage, 'p+ ul li , div:nth-child(6) p 
, #block-system-main div div li')
content <- html_text(contentHTML)
Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
}
```